# android - let user add a autocompletetextview on a button

Tags: android, button, autocompletetextview

I am working in android.
I am writing an application that requires the user to enter some words in AutoCompleteTextView.

**The thing is - the user can enter either 1, 2, 3 or more words (lets say up to 5). its his choice.**

I want the user to have the abitily to write one word in the first AutoCompleteTextView - and if he wants to add more, click a button that will add another AutoCompleteTextView , and so on.

**It would be ideal** if the buttun can be under the **first** AutoCompleteTextView and when you press it - it will add **another AutoCompleteTextView** and move down to be under the **second** AutoCompleteTextView.

thnaks !

Comment: Googling "add dynamic view android"

Comment: instead of multiple autocompletetextviews consider using multiautocompletetextview